# How to structure and manage a multi-user realm (such as a team)?

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm utilizing the Realm Platform/Cloud with my React Native app. My user-base are teams working together on documents. Because of this, it seems to make sense to create a single realm for each team, and allow the entire realm to sync for each user as part of that team.

However, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this outside of creating a realm for the very first user of the team, and then having the initial user create a permission token for each new user, which upon signup would accept the permissions and join that realm rather than creating a new realm.

**My first question:** Is that the correct way to do this?

**My second question:** (If this is the correct way) In the scenario that one of the invited users logs out and logs back in, I need to specify a realm URL for them to go to. When I loop through the permissions to find the realms that user has access to, there a few (including `perm` and `management`). How should I pinpoint the realm they were invited to?

One thought was to append `/team` to the end of realm names, this way I could always find the realm where the last 4 characters are `team`. Is that logical? Is that the way?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create the initial user using a node.js script which logs in as your admin user.

Comment: Instead of the `/team` idea, you could use query-based sync (https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#query-based-synced-realms).